# Create a shortcut for the guest OS (VMware)

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, shortcuts, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

Is it possible to create a desktop shortcut for the guest OS in VMware and use it to launch the guest OS directly without opening VMware?

- I'm using VMware Workstation Player on Windows 11

Comment: "launch the guest OS directly without opening VMware" :/

Comment: You can start a guest from a command line (so shortcut) .   https://developer.vmware.com/docs/powercli/latest/vmware.vimautomation.core/commands/start-vm/#Default  ....  But I think that will also start VMware. Vmware is need to run a guest machine. It does not run by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Two things about your question.

**(1)** For most applications, a VMware Guest needs VMware to be running for the guest to run a Guest machine

[VMware guest requirement](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Running-VMware-Workstation-without-the-GUI/td-p/263981)

> No. Workstation is designed for user-interactive VMs. In 6.x and
> newer, the ability was added to keep a VM running in the background
> AFTER it has been started up -- however the GUI must be started to
> start/run the guest, AND the user must stay logged in (i.e. the VM is
> running as a user process). If you want to run VMs as services, use
> VMware Server.

**(2)** Given the restriction in (1) you can run a VMware Guest from a command line (and so a shortcut).

[Start Guest from Command line](https://developer.vmware.com/docs/powercli/latest/vmware.vimautomation.core/commands/start-vm/#Default)

Start-VM
This cmdlet powers on the virtual machines specified by the VM parameter.

> Syntax Default  .
>
> Start-VM .
>
> -VM  <VirtualMachine[] .
>
> [-RunAsync] .
>
> [-Server  <VIServer[]>]  .
>
> [CommonParameters]  .

Now VMware Player is not the complete VMware experience, so with Player you will need to start Player and the Guest normally.